# ArcGIS Pro Page Query doesn't hide table of attribute

Tags: arcgis-pro, data-driven-pages, definition-query

I am switching to ArcGIS Pro from ArcMap and I'm facing a strange issue. Once I build spatial map series and several layers with Page Queries. The map view applies Page Query and update the layout as it should be. But the table of attributes does not hide the records, keeps showing all records no matter that a query is applied.

Has anyone faced this, is this a new away of page definition query or what?

This affects the legend, I have a huge legend and I want to hide records not used.

Comment: Are you using a Map Series?  You mention a model. Are you using ModelBuilder?  Are you using Table Frames or just opening attribute tables?  I think we need to see more detail about what you did in ArcMap and where you’re stuck trying to do the equivalent in ArcGIS Pro.

Comment: Thnx polygeo, i have mentioned model about model view (map view). So in map view everything is OK, its displayed what it should. But i mean the table of attribute of the layer that is applied Page Query, it has full records. Previously in desktop, also the table of attributes was reduced depending on Definition Query(page query),

Comment: So are you just interactively stepping through the pages of your map series using the List By Map Series Pages view of the Contents pane?

Comment: Exactly, when i switch into different sheets, it change the layout but the table of attribute has always all records.

Answer (score 0):

Did you ever figure this out?  This is driving me nuts, I just want to see the records per the page definition query, not all of them.

Comment: nope, as soon as there are only me and you that needs it, you know what I mean, for two people they are not going to update it :D

Comment: also having the issue and would like prior arcmap behavior.